# iOS/core-data: Can value for key access relationships?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an NSMutableArray of User objects i.e. NSManagedObjects.  The user objects don't have some biographical information that is in another object, Bio that is joined to User through a one-to-onerelationship . Is it possible to grab an array of objects based on the relationship?

The following line works great, creating an array of Usernames of the Users (uname is an attribute of User):

```
NSMutableArray * userNames = [[_users valueForKey:@"uname"] mutableCopy];
```

However, this line compiles but gives an error at runtime...

```
 NSMutableArray * firsts =[[_users valueForKey:@"bio.firstName"] mutableCopy]; 
//where bio is the name of the relationship to the Bio entity and firstName is the first name of the user.
```

The error it gives is:

`[NSNull length]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3ab0ca70

Answer (score 4):

Yes but you need to use `-valueForKeyPath:` instead of `-valueForKey:` that will tell the framework that you are going to be traversing relationships.